# Why does unlocking cursor with keyup behave the same as unlocking it with keydown?

Tags: unity, input

To understand the difference, let me review a bit about the behavior of `GetKeyUp` and `GetKeyDown` with the following code snippet.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Debug.Log("Escape Key Down");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Debug.Log("Escape Key Up");
    }
}
```

Right after pressing the `Esc` key (and holding it), a message "Escape Key Down" is produced. Later right after releasing the key, a message "Escape Key Up" will show. 
The behavior does make sense.

Now I apply this for toggling (locking/unlocking) the mouse cursor. Here is my code snippet.

```
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true; 
    }
}
```

Right after clicking the left mouse button, the cursor becomes invisible. However, right after pressing down the `Esc` key, the cursor becomes visible again. **The expected behavior is that the cursor will be visible right after releasing the `Esc` key rather than right after pressing the key.**

## Question

How to fix this abnormal behavior?

Comment: Doesn't pressing the escape key always break out of cursor lock, even if you delete your GetKeyUp code block entirely?

Comment: Ah, if that turned out to be the solution, post it as an Answer. It might help others. :)

Comment: You're welcome to, since you're the one who's tested it first-hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DMGregory's comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/182357/why-does-unlocking-cursor-with-keyup-behave-the-same-as-unlocking-it-with-keydow#comment326419_182357) is the answer.

> Doesn't pressing the escape key always break out of cursor lock, even if you delete your GetKeyUp code block entirely?

So I have to change `Escape` key to another key to avoid this problem.